# Route From Network Analyst Not Fully Displayed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network

I am working on a project for finding the optimized route solid waste pickup within a defined neighborhood.
These are my setting for route properties. The curb approach must always be on the right side of the vehicle.

[image: Analysis Setting for Layer Properties]
The system gave me a route once I hit the solve button and if I offset the route and add arrows to it to show the flow of the direction. I got the following

[image: Screen Shot of my suggested Route]
How come it didn't show the missing route (I drawn in red)?